# Can I avoid hardcoding file locations in SPSS syntax?

Tags: spss

I'm using SPSS 25 syntax to open and process a set of datafiles. I would like these syntax files to be as portable as possible. For that reason, I want the user to be able to select the file locations at runtime without having to recode the syntax itself.

I'm running Windows 10, although hopefully that doesn't matter. I do have the Python plugin for SPSS, although ideally this would be a base SPSS syntax solution.

In SPSS right now, I'm doing this:

```
GET
  FILE='C:\Users\xkcd\studies\project\rawdata'+
    '\reallyraw\veryraw.sav'
    PASSWORD='CorrectHorseBatteryStaple'.
DATASET NAME Demo WINDOW=FRONT.
```

In R, I would do this:

```
message("Where is the veryraw.sav file?")
demo<-fread(file.choose())
```

Ideally, the user would, at runtime, select the individual files one at a time.
Less ideally, the user would select a folder in which all of the files, with known names.

I could use FILE HANDLE so that the user would only have to hardcode a few folder locations, but that's less than ideal - I really would rather that the user isn't editing the syntax at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The obvious solution is to create a custom dialog which gets the file names/paths from the user and then runs the syntax with them. The users would have to install the custom dialog but it's a pretty easy process. If, on the other hand, you want to fully automate the process you might be able to use the [host](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_host_syntax.html#syn_host_syntax) command to search for the needed file and write it's path into a new text file. Then use syntax to extract the path from the text file and use it in further commands.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why not Python ? it would certainly open new possibilities. Do you plan to deploy this to computers with no python plug-in ? Otherwise, it's just a "plug-n-play" code which the user would run

Comment: using python here might be simpler, but I managed to find a fully automated solution with no Python. *This is a great question* - I will be using this code in a few of my projects from now on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the idea of a fully automated process - the following code will work assuming there is a specific file name you need to run your code on, and only one copy exists in the folder you are searching. This is **possible** to run on drive `C:` directly, but will take much less time to run if you can narrow down the path:

```
* this will create a text file that has the path of the required file.

HOST COMMAND=['dir /s /b "C:\Users\somename\*required file name.sav" > C:\Users\somename\tempname.sps'].

* now to read the name and put in in a handle.

DATA LIST file = "C:\Users\somename\tempname.sps" fixed / pth 1-500 (a).
exe.
string cmd(a500).
compute cmd=concat("file handle myfile / name='", rtrim(pth), "'.").
write out="C:\Users\somename\tempname.sps" /cmd.
exe.

* inserting the new syntax will activate the handle.

insert file = "C:\Users\somename\tempname.sps".
```

Now you can use the handle `myfile` in the syntax, e.g:

```
get file=myfile.
```

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful! It's not exactly what I was hoping for, since it doesn't quite match the file.choose() functionality, but it's still very helpful!

Comment: Yes, to actually get the user to select the file you can use a [custom dialog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/idh_idd_uibuilder.html#idh_idd_uibuilder), but that would require your users to install it (which is pretty [simple](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-custom-dialogs/)).